# Merging multiple files in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have several files (around 10 files) which I would like to merge together in Pig:

```
Student01.txt 
Student02.txt
...
Student10.txt
```

I am aware that I could merge two datasets together by:

```
data = UNION Student01, Student02
```

Is there any way that I could iterate over a loop to merge the dataset from Student01 to Student10?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the files are in the same format, then `LOAD` command allows you to read all files if you provide it *a directory or a glob*.

From docs -

> The input data to the load can be a file, a directory or a glob

Example

```
STUDENTS = LOAD("/path/to/students/Student*.txt") USING PigStorage();
```